# How to change the timezone of a TimeWithZone object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a model `Coupon` with an attribute `expired_at`, of class `DateTime` and before I save the record, I want to change the zone part of the field according to the user's choice. Say,

```
c = Coupon.new
c.expired_at = DateTime.now
c.expired_at_timezone = "Arizona"
c.save!
```

And in `coupon.rb`:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  def before_save
    # change the zone part here, leave the date and time part alone
  end
end
```

What I'm saying is if the admin wants the coupon expired at `2014-07-01 10:00 am`, Arizona time, the `expired_at` stored in the DB should be something like this:

```
Tue, 01 Jul 2014 10:00:00 MST -07:00
```

Is there any way I can modify the zone part only and leave the date and time part alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default timezone for your rails application by changing `config.time_zone` in your `environment.rb`. Usually by default it is set to UTC.

In your case each coupon has its own timezone. So you have to use a different approach.
You don't have to change your `save` logic. You just need to change your retrieval 
logic. Use the [in_time_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#M001459) method of Time class.

```
c =  Coupon.last
p c.expired_at.in_time_zone(c.expired_at_timezone)
# => Tue, 09 Mar 2010 02:06:00 MST -07:00
```

Otherwise you can override the `expired_at` method of your Coupon model.

```
def expired_at
  # access the current value of expired_at from attributes hash
  attributes["expired_at"].in_time_zone(self.expired_at_timezone)
end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
p Coupon.last.expired_at
# => Tue, 09 Mar 2010 02:06:00 MST -07:00
```

Comment: is it possible to rewrite expired_at method in coupon.rb?

def expired_at
  super.in_time_zone(expired_at_timezone)
end

Comment: I have updated my answer with the `expired_at` method. To get the current value of `expired_at` you have to access the `attributes` hash.

Comment: in_time_zone doesn't change time zone part ONLY. This is not the answer regarding to what the author asked.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save all your date in UTC after, you can compare by TimeZone.