# How to change the time zone on a TimeWithZone object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, activesupport

I'm working on an app which has its `config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'` (which is UTC +5:30), I'm trying to save the time for a particular object in EST/EDT (UTC -5:00/-4:00) from the ActiveAdmin panel.

Since it involves daylight savings, I'd rather not resort to manual calculations and transform the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object from UTC +530 into UTC -400. Is it possible to just change the zone part of a TimeWithZone object without converting it?

P.S. I did come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407494/for-timewithzone-object-how-to-change-the-zone-part-only). But it isn't have the answer I'm looking for.(one of the comments even mention it)

Comment: Also looking for something like change method of DateTime where we can specify timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

I've been scouring the internet for solutions to a similar problem that you've described and amazed that I couldn't find one. I eventually stumbled upon the `TimeWithZone#change` method when reading through the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-change

So if you just want to adjust the Zone without changing the Time, you can do

```
time.change(zone: "Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
```

and change it back to UTC again after the conversion if you like

```
time.change(zone: "Eastern Time (US & Canada)").in_time_zone("UTC")
```

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended that all datetime objects should **always** be stored in UTC -0000, as said [here](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/02/datetime-values-should-always-be-stored-in-utc/). If yet you want to convert it to do some calculations, use the `utc_offset` method or convert both objects to UTC by using the `utc` method, as seen [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html).

Comment: Sure, and I'm aware that Rails does internally stores DateTime objects in UTC (even if you have a set config.time_zone). I specifically need to be able to resolve the object instances into different time_zones. Since I'll be having users in India & the Eastern United States. This is a sensitive issue because the DateTime objects cascade down into other parts of my app. I want to be able to expire offers/events on exact times. Eg: An event starts exactly at 12:15 PM EDT, so the sales need to close by then. Currently since the app only resolves into IST, I'm manually calculating the offset.

Comment: @Ameen you can convert both times to UTC to check wether the sales need to close or not. Or, you can use `Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")` to change the time to whatever timezone you want to. To see all the available time zones' strings run `rake time:zones:all`